# Is git set 'git pull' with rebase by default for now? Which version when it start?

Tags: git

In the past, `git pull` is doing `git fetch` and `git merge`.So it always have merge commit.

But now I saw our team members, use 'git pull' when they have commits.
And won't have merge commit, because the commit time is later than the branch's last commit.

I have check the `git config --list` and it has `rebase.autosquash=true`.

Is git set `git pull` with rebase by default for now? Which version when it start?

Comment: Since Git [2.27](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.27.0.txt) they've warned you `git pull` *without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is discouraged*

Comment: Our oldest git version is 2.9.3. But thanks, you give me a hint. That, I could check the release note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the past, `git pull` is doing `git fetch` and `git merge`.

This is still the default.

> So it always have merge commit.

This, however, is not the case: `git merge` with no options *defaults* to doing a fast-forward operation instead of a merge, whenever this is possible.  A fast-forward operation is not a merge (even though Git refers to it as a "fast-forward merge") so it does not produce a merge commit.

You get a merge commit when:

- you force `git merge` to make one, using `--no-ff`; or
- a fast-forward is not possible (in which case `--no-ff`, if you set it, is redundant).

This is all quite configurable, though.

> But now I saw our team members, use 'git pull' when they have commits. And won't have merge commit, because the commit time is later than the branch's last commit.

The word *because* here is misplaced.  The time stamps on any given commit are quite independent of whether Git uses a merge commit.  There is no cause-and-effect relationship here.  Merging uses the *commit graph*, not any date-and-time-stamps on commits; the date-and-time-stamps are irrelevant to the graph structure.<sup>1</sup>

> I have check the git config --list and it has rebase.autosquash=true

That affects `git rebase`: it makes a plain `git rebase -i` act as though you ran `git rebase --autosquash -i`.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and search for `rebase.autoSquash`.

To make `git pull` act as if you had run `git pull --rebase`, there are multiple configuration options:

- `branch.name.rebase` can be set to anything that evaluates to boolean `true`;
- `pull.rebase` can be set to anything that evaluates to boolean `true`.

In addition, setting `branch.autoSetupRebase` directs branch-name-*creating* operations to set `branch.name.rebase` to `true`.  Again, see the configuration documentation for details, as this is highly configurable.

---

<sup>1</sup>For instance, we can have a series of commits `C-D-E` where the date and time stamp of commit `C` is in the 1970s, before Git even existed; the date and time stamp of commit `D` is set far in the future; and the date and time stamp of commit `E` is "right now".  This is not *normal* and strongly suggests that the date-stamps were faked.  But since Git does not depend on them,<sup>2</sup> it's harmless.

<sup>2</sup>Some features in Git speed up use *of* the commit graph by making assumptions about increasing date stamps.  To make this work correctly, some recent Git work now computes a "corrected commit timestamp" internally.  For an ordinary commit, the corrected commit timestamp of child `C` of parent `P` is `max(C.date, P.date+1)`, more or less.  For a root commit we simply use the date stamp as-is and for a multi-parent commit we find `max(P.date ∀ P ∈ parents)` and add 1 and use that as the other input to our outer `max` function.

Comment: I used to think `C-E` pull `C-D` become `C-D-E`, is because 'D' commit time before 'E', so it pull with rebase. And misunderstand what `rebase.autosquash=true` is doing for. Thanks to give me a lesson.